# Does android support CE-HTML?

Tags: android, html

I would like to know if Android 2.1 supports CE-HTML. If yes, please give me some pointers on how to use CE-HTML in Android.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but... Android==small hand-held devices with touch-screen interface; CS-HTML==extensions to normal HTML, designed for large (TV-sized) devices viewed from a distance with separate remote control. They couldn't be more different from each other if they tried. I don't know whether Android supports it, but I can't imagine any reason why it would.

Comment: it is not CS-HTML but CE-HTML(for consumer electronic devices, not only TV, but it can be other devices also)

Answer (score 1):

WebKit browsers (as the one in Android phones) will show CE-HTML pages, but will not allow CE-HTML media object playback.

CE-HTML is basically XHTML + CSS (TV) + ECMA 262 3rd, so it will work in every browser which supports forementioned standards.